# Select tag mobile screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a page for mobile devices with a select tag at the top, however, the only way I managed to get it to look like so.

[image]

is by using the zoom option in css, can anyone suggest a better way of achieving this and centering the select tag?

Edit: I'm trying to centre the select tag and make it bigger without using the zoom css option.

Comment: Could you clarify your question, I'm a little confused. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just edited it, please tell me if more detail is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the CSS for mobile devices the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` is very important:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Document Title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Document Description">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<style>

  .select-container {
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .select-container select {
    font-size: inherit;
  }

</style>

<body>

<div class="select-container">
  <label for="my-sort">Sort by:</label>
  <select name="sort" id="my-sort">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
  </select>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Preview at: http://jsfiddle.net/tkon99/w7g65/

**HTML:**

```
<p id="sorttext">Sort by:</p>
 <div id="selectholder">
   <select id="selector">
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#selectholder{
  text-align: center; /* centering select element */
  position: relative; /* making it relative so the text is next to it */
  top: -50px; /* value with which it's higher on the page than normal */
}

#selector{
      height: 30px; /* height of the select element */
      font-size: 25px; /* making font fill the element */
}

#sorttext{
      font-size: 25px; /* font size of the text next to the select element */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help : http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/X5YLw/1/

**html**

```
<select class="center large">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
```

**Center**

```
.center {
    display:block ;
  margin-left:auto ;
  margin-right:auto ;
}
```

**Width/height**

```
.large{
    height: 50px;
    width:200px;
   font-size: 28px;
}
```